# How do I overwrite every fifth instance of an element in an array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

I'll start by saying that I'm new to rails. This question is for a class I'm currently taking. The lesson topic is CRUD, and the content is a db that stores posts along with their titles and comments.

The instructions are as follows:

> Overwrite the title of every fifth instance of Post with the text "CENSORED".

This is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index

  @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end
end
```

This is my view file:

```
<h1>All Posts</h1>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
          <%= link_to post.title, post %>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

I'm not really sure where to even start and would really appreciate any help at all. A point in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is this overwrite in the database sense, or overwrite in the view sense?

Comment: Just in the view sense, they just wanted posts that might have bad language to show "censored", not to change the post itself.

Comment: And thanks everyone for their help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@posts = Post.all
@posts.each_with_index do |post, index| 
  if index % 5 == 4 # since index starts at 0, every 5th object will be at positions 4, 9, 14, 19 etc.
    # Do the change on post object
    post.update_attributes(title: 'CENSORED')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rajesh Omanakuttan! I was trying `if post % 5`... This makes sense and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways, where `@posts = Post.all`, and assuming the first post is to be censored:

**#1**

```
e = [[:CENSOR] + [:PUBLISH]*4].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:CENSOR, :PUBLISH, :PUBLISH, :PUBLISH, :PUBLISH]]:cycle>    
@posts.each {|p| p.update_attributes(title: 'CENSORED') if e.next==:CENSOR }
```

**#2**

```
(0...@posts.size).step(5) {|i| @posts[i].update_attributes(title: 'CENSORED')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `each_with_index` instead of `each`; if the index modulo 5 is zero, censor it.

Comment: `index % 5 == 0` will yield unexpected results. In particular, the first item will be censored too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Not unexpected to me. OP just said every fifth, without specifying which one should be the first censored one. Also, it is trivial to offset, and OP should be able to deduce how. (Actually, someone already posted it, so...)

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to *display* "CENSORED" for every fifth element, then I'd take a look at each_with_index: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index

Answer (score 0):

**If @posts is in array form**

```
@posts.each_with_index do |post,index|
  post.update!(title: "CENSORED") if index % 5 == 0
end
```

OR

**If @posts is in your database**

```
@posts.each do |post|
  post.update!(title: "CENSORED") if (post.id % 5 == 0)
end
```

Comment: This assumes that id is integer. And id sequence doesn't have holes.